# What is the reason Content-Disposition is not included in the response obtained in HttpClient?

Tags: javascript, angular

Going to url in which a .zip file is downloaded, this is the response I get

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=2021002974.zip
Content-Type: application/zip
Date: Tue, 03 Aug 2021 21:33:41 GMT
Expires: 0
Pragma: no-cache
Server: nginx/1.16.1
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Vary: Origin
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Method
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Headers
Vary: Origin
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Method
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Headers
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block

* Received 15.4 KB chunk
***
***
```

As you can see, the Content-Disposition header is included in whose value comes the name of the file. I need to get this value to name the file to download.

If I test this endpoint with different http clients the response includes the Content-Disposition header. When I make the request using the browser, I can see in devtools that Content-Disposition is also included in the response. But when trying to get the value inside httpClient the Content-Disposition header has null value. This is the code that I am implementing

```
const url = `https://some.domain.com/some/path/download?token=${token}`;
const fileType = 'zip';

this.httpClient
.get(url, {
  observe: 'response',
  responseType: 'blob',
  params: new HttpParams().set('format', fileType),
  headers: new HttpHeaders().set(interceptorSkipHeader, 'true'),
})
.subscribe(
  (response: HttpResponse<Blob>) => {
    console.log(response.headers.keys());

    const blob = new Blob([response.body], {
      type: `application/${fileType}`,
    });

    URL.createObjectURL(blob);

    saveAs(blob, 'test.zip');

    this.message = 'Done!';
  },
  (error) => {
    console.error(error.message);

    this.message = `Invalid token`;
  }
);
```

The output of `console.log(response.headers.keys());` is:

```
[
  "cache-control",
  "content-type",
  "expires",
  "pragma"
]
```

Any idea why Content-Disposition is not included in httpClient?

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Expose-Headers